# Joomla and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Is there specific documentation available on Joomla regarding making database queries via MySQL in PHP?

What I'm really looking for:

- Whether or not Joomla has it's own database wrapper implemented, and if not, is it recommended to create one using the specified config parameters.
- Whether or not Joomla has the capability to parameterize their queries to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Joomla has it's own OOP defined to deal with databases.

Usually, you will deal with code like this:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "SELECT * FROM #__example_table WHERE id = 999999;";
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Can read more here: [How to use the database classes in your script](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script)

Comment: By the way, Antonio, do you know whether or not joomla actually sanitizes their queries via the DB wrapper? This is something I haven't been able to find in their documentation.

Comment: @Holland Nope Joomla doesn't sanitize queries automatically - http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries

Comment: This is a really old answer where the code worn't work in any version after 1.5.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has its own class, it's the class JDatabase if I recall correctly. There's an [**API page**](http://api.joomla.org/)
 where you get all the documented code on the framework.

A this [**Joomla WIKI**](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script), then, you have example on how to use the database class. Don't know if updated to the latest (1.7) version, but I'm pretty sure it works the same (at least did for the 1.6)